# Json array Count in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle19c

I'm having below value in the column "c1" (which is of datatype clob) on table "t1" in oracle (version 19c )

**Data**

```
[{"ID":"1","DUPID":"1"},{"ID":"2","DUPID":"2"},{"ID":"3","DUPID":"3"},{"ID":"4","DUPID":"4"},{"ID":"5","DUPID":"5"},{"ID":"6","DUPID":"6"},{"ID":"7","DUPID":"7"}]
```

I would like to get the count of the array. I've queried like below. But would like to know if there is a better way to achieve this.

**Query used:**

```
select regexp_count ( c1,'},{' ) +1 from t1 ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
    JSON_value('[0,1,2,3,4]', '$.size()')
from dual ;
```